# Django - POST method not working for those forms created within a FOR loop in template

Tags: django

I'm using a for loop in a template to create multiple forms with `method="post"` that work with Ajax. But only the form for the **first** element of `items_list` works fine, the rest do not work at all showing **error 405 0 Method Not Allowed**. I think they all should work the same way. And just wondering if this issue was caused by a for loop or something else.

**cart_items.html:**

```
<script>
    $(document).ready(function () {
        $("#remove").click(function (event) {
            event.preventDefault();
            $.ajax({
                url: '{% url "cart:remove_from_cart" %}',
                type: "POST",
                dataType: 'json',
                data: {bookID: $('#idInput').val()},
                success: function (response_data) {
                    alert('works fine')
                },
                error: function (response_data) {
                    console.log('error occurred');
                }
            });
        });
    });
</script>

{% for book in items_list %}
    <div class="items">
        <p id="title"> {{ book.book.title }}, quantity: {{ book.quantity }} </p>
        <form method="post">
            {% csrf_token %}
            <input id="idInput" value="{{ book.book.id }}" >
            <button id="remove" type="submit"> Remove</button>
        </form>
    </div>
{% endfor %}
```

The code in the function body below is just for testing. Once the first form works, I guess the problem was not caused by the function view.

**cart/views.py:**

```
@csrf_exempt
def remove_books(request):
    cart = Cart.objects.get(user=request.user)
    if request.method == 'POST':
        passed_id = request.POST['bookID']
        secured_id = int(passed_id)
        response_data = {
            'quantity': secured_id
        }
        return JsonResponse(response_data)
```

Comment: The id needs to be unique: here you define *multiple* buttons with the *same* `id="remove"`, furthermore this will probably trigger the `<form>` submit before the JavaScript does, so you should probably either drop the JavaScript, or change the button to just `<button name="remove">remove</button>`.

Comment: @WillemVanOnsem ah I see thank u

Comment: You need to post `csrfmidlewaretoken` too in ajax.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
<script>
    $(document).ready(function () {
        $(".remove").click(function (event) {
            // event.preventDefault();  // don't think it should be required with button type=button
            var book_id = $(this).parent().find('.idInput').val(); // find correct input box. 
            var csrf = $('input[name="csrfmiddlewaretoken"]').val(); // get csrf token in variable.
            // there are multiple ways to get csrf token, I personally like this ^^, see https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/ref/csrf/#ajax for more
            $.ajax({
                url: '{% url "cart:remove_from_cart" %}',
                type: "POST",
                dataType: 'json',
                data: {
                    bookID: book_id,
                    csrfmiddlewaretoken: csrf // add csrf token to post data
                },
                success: function (response_data) {
                    alert('works fine')
                },
                error: function (response_data) {
                    console.log('error occurred');
                }
            });
        });
    });
</script>

{% csrf_token %} <!-- It will render a hidden input field with csrf token in it. Keep it outside for loop but in html. No need to render exactly same element multiple times. -->
{% for book in items_list %}
    <div class="items">
        <p class="title"> {{ book.book.title }}, quantity: {{ book.quantity }} </p>
        <form method="post">
            <input class="idInput" value="{{ book.book.id }}" > <!-- use class not id -->
            <button class="remove" type="button"> Remove</button> <!-- you can use button type=button to avoid form submit and hence avoid event.preventDefault(); in js -->
        </form>
    </div>
{% endfor %}
```

Comment: thank u so much, it worked. but it complains about `csrfmiddlewaretoken: {{ csrf_token }}` this line

Comment: hold on a sec, I will fix it. Not sure whats wrong, but we will use different approach for csrf. I will comment again when done editing my answer

Comment: @VaibhavVishal how did you fix it? I'm having same issue and didnt find a solution yet.

Comment: @OliviaLundy It's two years old answer so I don't remember exactly, but looking at the edit history of the answer, I think I have fixed it.